# Locking/unlocking a synchronisation primitive in different functions from code design point of view

Tags: multithreading

Assume that a mutex or spinlock is locked in one function and unlocked in another (in the same thread). In which cases is that considered appropriate and in which inappropriate? I'm interested in design/pattern/architectural perspective of this question.

I'm almost certain that usually this approach is undesirable, because thus we can span a responsibility of releasing a lock across  unrelated chunks of code, though I do not have enough experience to answer this question by myself.

PS: I've looked at the following link, and it doesn't help me :
[Linux Kernel - Can I lock and unlock Spinlock in different functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761757/linux-kernel-can-i-lock-and-unlock-spinlock-in-different-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The further apart the lock and unlock actions are, the harder it is to reason about the code.  Having them in separate functions makes it much harder than even greatly separated in the same function (assuming that the functions aren't merely wrappers around the lock/unlock but have other behaviour as well).

If a means to automatically pair lock and unlock is available (such as with Java's `lock` keyword or C++'s `std::lock_guard`), prefer to use it.  These constructs help ensure correct behaviour in the exceptional cases as well as in the 'happy path' through your code.

If you really need to hold a lock beyond a function return, *please* ensure that it's explicitly noted in the function's comment (in both declaration and implementation files if it's C or C++) and state which function should be called to release the lock.

Usually, such an extended hold on a lock can be better represented as a state variable (that must itself be accessed atomically) rather than as a lock.